# boolean recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion, boolean

I'm trying to see if a is a power of b. For this to be true a needs to be divisible by b and a/b needs to be a power of b as well. I'm struggling with the recursion here as it seems like it'll go on forever. Can anyone help?

```
def is_power(a,b):
    if(a % b == 0):
        a = a/b
        if(is_power(a,b)):
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: You should also mention the input that gives you infinite reursion.

Comment: Unless this is Python 2, you need `a // b` here. If you divide `a/b`, you get a float, not an int, and rounding errors can mean that `a % b` is, say, 1e-302, or something  else very close to, but not equal to, 0.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative approach is to take the logarithm of `a` with respect to the base `b`.  If the result is a whole number, than `b**x = a` for some `x`

```
from math import log

def is_power(a, b):
    return log(a, b).is_integer()
```

Comment: I doubt someone would be trying to solve this with recursion unless they were doing an assignment specifically saying they have to use recursion.

Answer (score 3):

What you're missing is a base case that can return `True`. Your function only returns `True` if a recursive call to the same function returns `True`. Which can only happen if another recursive call to the same function returns `True`. Which can… and so on. So, the only things that can possibly happen are returning `False`, or recursing forever (or, rather, recursing 1000 times until you get an exception).

More generally, any recursive solution needs two parts: a base case that you can solve immediately, and a recursive case that reduces the problem down toward the base case. You've written the second part—the hard part—but missed the first part.

One obvious base case is either `a == b`, or `a == 1`. If either of those is true, then you know that `a` is a power of `b` (the first or zeroth power, respectively), so you can immediately return `True`. So, let's try one of those:

```
def is_power(a,b):
    if a == b:
        return True
    if(a % b == 0):
        a = a/b
        if(is_power(a,b)):
            return True
    return False
```

Now it works for *many* values—`is_power(16, 2)`, `is_power(6561, 3)`, etc.

But, unless this is Python 2, there's another problem: `a/b` returns a float, not an int, which means that your next recursive step could, because of float rounding issues, calculate `a % b` and get something like 1e-302 instead of 0, so `a % b == 0` will be False, and you'll go too far and keep on dividing. This would eventually reach 0 and finally return True (the right answer for the wrong reason), but if it takes more than 1000 steps to get there, you'll hit the recursion limit first and raise an exception.

To fix that, just use `//` instead of `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a exit condition:

```
def is_power(a,b):
    if a == b:
        return True
    elif a % b == 0:
        a = a/b
        return is_power(a,b)
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

If mod is 0, you have to continue with the recursion until a/b is equal to 1 (meaning equals):

```
def is_power(a,b):
    if(a % b == 0):
        a = a/b
        if(a == 1):
            return True
        else:
            return is_power(a,b)
    else:
      return False

print(is_power(16,2))
True
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def is_power(a,b):
    if(a % b == 0):
        a = a/b
        return a == 1 or is_power(a,b)
    return False
```